# couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials error: You must be logged in to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-config

I created the eks cluster trying to connect it with local cli, for that, I installed the aws-cli and also provide the right 'aws configure' credentials. The user which I am using to connect with the aws have the EKS related policy. Still I am getting the following Error ...

```
E0209 21:09:44.893284 2465691 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0209 21:09:45.571635 2465691 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0209 21:09:46.380542 2465691 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0209 21:09:47.105407 2465691 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0209 21:09:47.869614 2465691 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well in my case, the aws keys with which I created the cluster and with which I configured the kubectl were different. The two of them were different aws identities.

To give another user permission to access the control pane follow this

[How do I resolve the error You must be logged in to the server Unauthorized when I connect to the Amazon EKS API server](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/).

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

My problem got solved by removing `cli_auto_prompt` in the AWS profile

```
vi ~/.aws/config

[default]
region = us-west-2
# cli_auto_prompt = on

[profile <X>]
region = us-west-2
# cli_auto_prompt = on
```

Also, make sure to update the `kubeconfig` one more time after the above change. Please be sure to use the correct cluster name as well as region and also make sure the logged in user in your CLI do have admin permissions on [EKS RBACK](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error).

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <EKS_CLUSTER_NAME> --region us-west-2
```

Comment: aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <EKS_CLUSTER_NAME> --region us-west-2

fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was working with a different AWS account than usual, so I set the environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
```

I do not need them to access other AWS accounts from my computer - credentials are managed differently, but I had to remove those variables to make the usual connection work again.

In similar scenarios you may need to:

1. Remove them as well,
2. Change them to correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not set to the correct AWS account where the relevant EKS is set.

Use "aws configure list" to verify you are connected to the correct profile (which is probably not correct).

Use "aws configure" to set the correct account.
Or use relevant AWS env parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error

this worked for me, it was due to aws cli user is not the user used to create the cluster
solved when same user used for both

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got a similar error by having the "default" systemd cgroup driver (that is Kubernetes' default nowadays). However, if you don't use docker but containerd + runc, *this* will default to using cgroupfs cgroup driver. This difference will not show up as an actual error BUT it will lead to above error.

So basically I did not do THIS: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd-systemd

Answer (score -2):

The same error happened to me on k3d. Seems like the certificates were expired. I tried this and it worked

```
k3d kubeconfig get <name_of_cluster>
k3d kubeconfig merge <name_of_cluster> -d –u 
k3d cluster stop <name_of_cluster> 
k3d cluster start <name_of_cluster>
```